# Nginx: webserver can't block subfiles and sub-directories

Tags: nginx

I am trying to block a directory `/denydir` and all its files, following the very first location block in my nginx config file:

```
...

location ^~ /denydir/ {
  deny all;
  return 403;
}

...
```

this is work for `denydir` only, however all its file still accessible.

any help?

Comment: Did you reset the browser cache before testing this?

Comment: @RichardSmith for sure, it is not caching issue.

Comment: This location will match any URI that begins with `/denydir/` unless there is a more specific `location` or some `rewrite` logic that defeats it. Without seeing the entire configuration together with access and error logs, it's difficult to advise further.